# Making image overflow while scrollbar for text is still present

Tags: css, overflow

[An overflow-x, overflow-y pen by CSS Tricks](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/5ff94380c4edf4d0b1409504ed1f3315)
Hey, does someone have an idea how it may be possible to make the image in this CSS (please use the Codepen link) overflow the box, while overflow-y: scroll is still applied?

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis 
    officiis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis 
    officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum 
    incidunt.Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.
  </p>
</div>

.box {
   border: 1px solid #222;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it, albeit a very hacky one. I put `position:absolute` on the image, which makes it ignore the overflow properties. Then I added a placeholder, which will cover the space the image covers so the text won't get pushed up to where the image is.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I just noticed, that in your codepen there is an `overflow-x: scroll;` while in the question itself it says `overflow-y: scroll;`. Can you specify which one you mean and tell me if I understood you correctly?

**Edit2:** I corrected my code snippet to fit to the question.

**Edit3:** If possible, I recommend taking the image out of the container. This makes the scrollbar visible and also doesn't need any placeholder or additional wrapper of any sort:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.placeholder {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150" alt="" />
  <div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: scroll (i.e. the opposite of what was in the codepen). Apologies.

Comment: I am looking into your solution now though

Comment: Gotcha. I went with the codepen, so obviously my solution is not going to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @arw89 I updated my answer, so maybe this will be what you're looking for.